# How to send activation emails for service

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2

I have a web service hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance, running PHP in the backend. My question is as follows:

How should I best design and implement activation emails for my service, such that they by-pass many types of spam-filters. I will primarily be emailing school/universities email addresses, as my service is an educational website (email addresses like Bob@harvard.edu, etc..)

Currently I am implementing this by using PHP mail() and sending emails to users through my own EC2 hosting service. This is becoming problematic as many spam filters seem to swat of the home-grown kinds of mail systems. Does it make sense to go for a paid option? Is there a way to do this without having to put down some serious $$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Consider Amazon's SES, for starters. Most e-mails sent directly from EC2 instances will be spam filtered, as spammers love the idea of being able to fire up dozens of servers on Amazon's high-speed network for short spamming runs.

Comment: @ceejayoz Just took a look at it and it looks PERFECT. How would I generate automatic SES messages, though? From reading the little blurb about SES it looks like Amazon gives you a dashboard with which to send emails. Can I do this programmatically from within PHP?

Comment: SES is intended to be used entirely programmatically. The AWS SDK for PHP includes functions you can integrate into your code.

Comment: @ceejayoz do you have a link to that SDK/examples of how it's used? Thanks again!

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-SES/6867006791049823 might have answered my own comment...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite easy to get flagged for spam if you're sending from your own box. I think your best (and easiest) option is to go for one of the established email-as-a-service providers, such as [sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com) or [mailjet](http://mailjet.com)

They all have a (generous) free tier and good librairies for PHP. You can see this comparison of [transactional email providers](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/transactional-emailing-providers-mailjet-sendgrid-critsend) for more info

**Disclaimer**: I'm one of the devs at mailjet

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure: I am one of the developers behind AlphaMail**

I recently answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802506/340736) (includes PHP example). What I think you should do is use a Transactional Email Service such as:

- [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se/alpha-mail/)
- Mandrill
- SendGrid

At the same time, if it's not done already, add a SPF and DKIM DNS-record to your domain. And your activation emails will swoosh right by the spamfilter.